# Ionic JavaScript function executes without waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following method that is called on a pages ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
this.devicesinfo.fetchdata().then(response => {
  this.deviceSub = this.devicesinfo.alldevices.subscribe(alldevices => {
 this.deviceinfosarr = alldevices;
 alert(JSON.stringify(this.deviceinfosarr[0]));
 this.doneloading = true;
} );
});
}
```

Here is the fetch data method in the device info service class.

```
  async fetchdata() {

     return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getuserdevicesIDs().then(response => {
             alert(this.arrIDs.IDs+ ' IDs I have');
                     // get all of the IDS of the devices a user owns.
        // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
             this.getdeviceinfo().then(res => {              // Get the information of a specific device
          const device = (res);

          this.deviceinfos[0] = device;
        });

    });

      resolve(true); // when you want to return a value in promise
      });
  // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-keyword



 }
```

My goal is for the NgOnit to wait for fetch data to finish before doing all of the other methods in the then but at the moment those are firing immediately whilst the fetch data is still busy. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When Angular loads component, it runs different lifecycle hooks look at ([Official docs here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks))

In your case `ngOnInit()` will fire before `fetchdata()` You need to update your code to run in a sequential manner.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how my code would have to be altered